# Switch off Hyper-V without disable functionality in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, vmware-workstation, hyper-v

Since I must use also VMWare I need to temporarily turn off Hyper-V

In Windows 8 I used

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

to disable hypervisor, and:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

to re-enable it.

In this way, after a normal reboot, VMware see Hyper-V as disabled and works fine

Unfortunately in Windows 8.1 using this command, VMWare doesn't start because see Hyper-V as enabled and I must use

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

and

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
```

This, unlike the previous way, doesn't simply turn-off Hyper-V, but disable the whole functionality that every time is unistalled and reinstalled.

Is there any other way to switch off-on Hyper-V without using dism?

Comment: On 64 bit Windows, the command `bcdedit` can be found in %WINDIR%/Sysnative, for those of you having trouble locating it. See http://superuser.com/a/886278/209016

Comment: You can use [Hyper-V Switch](https://github.com/dg9ngf/HyperVSwitch) to automate the task of toggling Hyper-V and rebooting. I've made this little tool and it works on my Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Thank you for the command `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`. I was trying it as `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype on` since morning ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was caused by a setup corruption occurred after the upgrade, reinstalling both VMware and Hyper-V, the solution to disable and re-enable the Hypervisor launch, still works.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 8.1 and VMWare Workstation 10.03 you can use both Hyper-V and VMWare except I suspect you are not getting full virtualization under VMWare. It will only let you run 32-bit VMs with possibly other limitations.

Turning it off through boot entry allows you to run 64-bit VMs again without uninstalling the Hyper-V feature. Either the hypervisorlaunchtype setting being on off or Auto there were no messages about Hyper-V in VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: When I disabled the hypervisor using bcdedit OR dism on Windows 10, the PC would no longer shutdown or sleep after the next reboot. So if you encounter this problem you may be forced to reenable it.

[Edit: I determined my problem was due to Hybrid Sleep no longer working for whatever reason. Having the hypervisor disabled or uninstalled allowed my PC to use Hybrid Sleep which wasn't working. Disabling Hybrid Sleep in Power Options fixed my issue and allowed me to keep the hypervisor disabled.]

Comment: I use Windows 10 without any problem with the command. There is some other system problem or misconfiguration in your pc.