# bcdedit.exe is not recognized... Win 8.1

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 8.1, and when I tried to use `bcdedit.exe` (for the first time on this install) it told me that:

```
'bcdedit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

I found this odd because:

- My `PATH` variable includes `C:\Windows\System32`
- bcdedit.exe is in System32
- I'm running the command from an elevated command prompt (not through some other language)

I tried a variety of other things, including using `cd` to go to the folder and then putting in `bcdedit.exe` (instead of bcdedit). No luck. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: This indicates your system image is corrupt this isn't a permission problem, can you run sfc?

Comment: Is this a fresh installation? What's your `PATHEXT` variable (`echo %PATHEXT%`)? Could you provide your entire `PATH` in case there's some syntax error in there? What does `where bcdedit` output?

Answer (score 10):

Open an elevated command prompt.

You can use this to see if bcdedit is damaged:

> sfc /VERIFYFILE=C:\windows\system32\bcdedit.exe

If the file is fine you will get an output like this:

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violoations.

If the file is damaged you can try to replace from backups using:

> sfc /scannow

If for any reason that fails you could always try downloading the [Windows 8.1 Enterprise](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-1-enterprise) trial, install it in a virtual machine, and copy the bcdedit.exe from it.

Answer (score 8):

This could also be due to running a 64-bit OS, in which case you need to access BCDEDIT from C:\Windows\Sysnative\bcdedit

Comment: Agreed, this can happen if you are running Windows x64 but your cmd program is x86 (running from \Windows\SysWOW64\), then bcdedit is not available. When you use "\Widnows\sysnative" in such scenario, you are referring to the x64 system folder.

Comment: Wow, its the same error msg as Linux! "No such file or directory" when its actually a 32bit vs 64bit issue. 

Digging deeper, its actually the binary interpreter that is printing the msg

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166755/home-amnesia-myfile-command-not-found-64-bit-executable-64-bit-kernel

Comment: In Windows 10 (64-bit) there is no C:\Windows\Sysnative spoke too soon :(

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Windows 10, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824048/bcdedit-file-output-doesnt-work-but-other-commands-do

"On 64-bit windows whenever a 32-bit app attempts to access %windir%\System32 directory, the access will be redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64. This process is transparent to the application and it still thinks it is accessing %windir%\System32 directory."

%windir%\SysWOW64\bcdedit.exe does not exist, which causes the error